# Hausdroff convergence and interior

Tags: general-topology, hausdorff-measure

Let $F_n$ be  non empty compact sets of $\mathbb{R^n}$ such that $F_n$ converges to a non empty compact set $F$ in sense of Hausdorff metric,

I would like to know what the  conditions are, if there exist, that we must consider so that the interior of $F_n$denoted $\mathring{F_n}$ converges to $\mathring{F}$

Comment: You are using $n$ in two different ways.

Comment: yes we can said "..compact set  in $\mathbb{R^p}$

Comment: You wrote "Let $F_n$ be  non empty compact sets of $\mathbb{R^n}$"

Answer (score 1):

A trivial case is when each $\mathring{F_n}$ is dense in $F_n$ and $\mathring{F}$ is dense in $F$,
because then Hausdorff distance $d_H$ between $F_n$ and $\mathring{F_n}$ is zero, and $d_H(F,\mathring{F})=0$ too.

Comment: yes this is the naturel condition , but I forgot to said $\mathring{F_n}$ convergence to $\mathring{F}$ in sens of the  complementary Hausdorff metric